# On form start up my check box is always selecting on first row

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, checkbox, focus

How to unselect my check box on application start up. each time when i start the application, my first row is coming as blue color.
i **tried giving `control.focus` to a text box, then also its not moving**. My check box is added programatically. How to remove this??

[image]

codes:

```
  public delegate void CheckBoxClickedHandler(bool state);
    public class DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCellEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        bool _bChecked;
        public DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCellEventArgs(bool bChecked)
        {
            _bChecked = bChecked;
        }
        public bool Checked
        {
            get { return _bChecked; }
        }
    }

    class DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
    {
        Point checkBoxLocation;
        Size checkBoxSize;
        bool _checked = false;
        Point _cellLocation = new Point();
        System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState _cbState =
            System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal;
        public event CheckBoxClickedHandler OnCheckBoxClicked;

        public DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell()
        {
        }

        protected override void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics,
            System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds,
            System.Drawing.Rectangle cellBounds,
            int rowIndex,
            DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState,
            object value,
            object formattedValue,
            string errorText,
            DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
            DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
            DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
        {
            base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex,
                dataGridViewElementState, value,
                formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle,
                advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
            Point p = new Point();
            Size s = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(graphics,
            System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);
            p.X = cellBounds.Location.X +
                (cellBounds.Width / 2) - (s.Width / 2);
            p.Y = cellBounds.Location.Y +
                (cellBounds.Height / 2) - (s.Height / 2);
            _cellLocation = cellBounds.Location;
            checkBoxLocation = p;
            checkBoxSize = s;
            if (_checked)
                _cbState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.
                    CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal;
            else
                _cbState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.
                    CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal;
            CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox
            (graphics, checkBoxLocation, _cbState);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point p = new Point(e.X + _cellLocation.X, e.Y + _cellLocation.Y);
            if (p.X >= checkBoxLocation.X && p.X <=
                checkBoxLocation.X + checkBoxSize.Width
            && p.Y >= checkBoxLocation.Y && p.Y <=
                checkBoxLocation.Y + checkBoxSize.Height)
            {
                _checked = !_checked;
                if (OnCheckBoxClicked != null)
                {
                    OnCheckBoxClicked(_checked);
                    this.DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
                }

            }
            base.OnMouseClick(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not include links to external web sites as supporting details for your question. Please do read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn about how to present your question in a useful, answerable way.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am sorry for that..